# Selenium Junit Writing Value of webelement into excel

Tags: excel, selenium, junit

In Selenium using Junit I am creating a registration into a website. Once the registration is successful a MRN number will be generated . I want to write this MRN number from the website into Excel sheet .Which I will be using for my further test cases .
   When I am trying to write it I am getting a error as type Mismatch .As the value to be written into the excel is String and I am fetching a webelement .Can one help me and let me know the method to write the value of a webelement into excel sheet .

Here is my logic

```
   boolean fieldtoverify =   AppLogin.f1.findElement(By.id("navigation:mrnoId")).isDisplayed();
WebElement MRN= AppLogin.f1.findElement(By.id("navigation:mrnoId"));

testreport tr = new testreport();
ExcelHelp ers = new ExcelHelp(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\TestData\\testdata.xlsx");
if(fieldtoverify){
    //Update test case execution report
    rNum=ers.findrownum("Registration", "MRN", 1);
    ers.datawrite("Registration", rNum, "MRN", MRN);
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
WebElement MRN = AppLogin.f1.findElement(By.name("navigation:mrnoId"));      
String MRNValue = MRN.getAttribute("value");
```

to get value from `WebElement`

Comment: Thanks @Karna .But Its not fetching the value present in textbox.Its just displaying blank spaces. Here is the property of my webelement <input type="text" readonly="readonly" style="width:197px;height:20px;background:#c0d3f0;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;" value="JM02524" name="navigation:mrnoId" id="navigation:mrnoId">

Comment: @user3356119: It should work. Debug and check if you are getting expected values for element

Comment: Yes.WhenI debugged its showing blank value.                 WebElement MRN=AppLogin.f1.findElement(By.name("navigation:mrnoId"));
 String MRNValue = MRN.getAttribute("value");

Comment: Only for this element it is displaying blank.I tried with other webelements value is getting displayed . Is it because its a read only. type <input type="text" readonly="readonly" style="width:197px;height:20px;background:#c0d3f0;font-size:18px;font-weight:bol‌​d;" value="JM02524" name="navigation:mrnoId" id="navigation:mrnoId">   .I really dont have an idea Please help